# how to mv/rename multiple files by adding current date on files names

Tags: rename, mv

I need to adapt a bash script on Red Hat that mv/renames multiple files and adds current date on their names. For example, I have bulk of files below:

> **P**BSS4C.SASS.CCAC.I101010.P**211008**

> **P**BSS4C.SASS.CSVC.I102210.P**211008**

(28 more files like this which ones begins with **PBSS4C.*** and ends with ***.P211008**)

In this file **P**211008 stands for process date. I need to replace to process date with the current date in the filename and replace **P** with **T** at the begining of the filenames.

expected result:

> **T**BSS4C.SASS.CCAC.I101010.P**211011**

> **T**BSS4C.SASS.CSVC.I102210.P**211011**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "current date" - which date is it exactly? The date/time when your command is run for each individual file, or when the command was started to run for the batch of files? This may sound like nitpicking, put consider edge cases when you run it via a script around midnight...

Comment: Actually system date which defined at the begining of script. Sorry for forgot to mention it.  `DATE=date +'%y%m%d'`

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Linux OS

Comment: OK but which one?

Comment: Using linux disturbution Redhat 7.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to `perl-rename` (often called `rename` on Debian-based systems), you can do:

```
rename -n "s/^P/T/; s/\.P211008$/\.P$(date +'%y%m%d')/" PBSS4C.*P211008
```

The `-n` will cause `rename` to just print the changes it would do without actually renaming anything. If you're confident that does what you want, run it again without the `-n`.

If you don't have `perl-rename`, you can do:

```
date=$(date +'%y%m%d')
for i in PBSS4C.*P211008; do 
    newName=${i/P/T} 
    newName=${newName/.P211008/}
    echo mv -- "$i" "$newName."P"$date"; 
done
```

Here too, once you've run this and confirmed that it does what you want, run it again without the `echo` to actually rename the files.

Comment: It did work. Thanks a lot.